# Edit a button by its given name

Tags: c#, winforms

I am generating x amount of buttons and I give all of them a unique name.

After all those are generated, I want to edit one of them without regenerating them so I was wondering if I could get a component by its name?

I am using WinForms

Comment: what are you using? WinForms, WPF, WEB ???

Comment: Have you tried to type button name in code editor?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy the button is in a different scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your form (or some container control on your form). With LINQ you can select buttons and then find first button with required name:

```
var button1 = Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "button1");
```

Or if you want to search child controls recursively

```
 var button1 = Controls.Find("button1", true)
                       .OfType<Button>()
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Without LINQ you can use method [Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of ControlCollection:

```
Control[] controls = Controls.Find("button1", true);
if (controls.Length > 0)
{
    Button button1 = controls[0] as Button;
}
```

Comment: This looks neat. However, I get a NullReferenceException when I try to use it as a button. (The button1 var). Should I check if it is an button even if it is said ofType<Button>?

Comment: FirstOrDefault returns default value if there is no button with name you search. Default value for Button is null. So yes, you should check for null to verify if button was found. Also make sure you are using Controls collection of control which you have added buttons to

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
Control myControl = Controls.Find("textBox1");
```

Now, beware that you have to do proper casting hen found, because Find returns a control.

Answer (score 0):

> After all those are generated, I want to edit one of them without
>   regenerating them so I was wondering if I could get a component by its
>   name?

```
var myButton = Controls.Find("buttonName", true).FirstOrDefault(); //Gets control by name
if(myButton != null)
{
    if (myButton.GetType() == typeof(Button)) //Check if selected control is of type Button
    {
       //Edit button here...
    }
    else
    {
       //Control isn't a button
    }
}
else
{
    //Control not found.
}
```

Make sure you add a reference to: linq.

Comment: Are you sure there is exists `Find(string)` method in `ControlCollection`?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy edited answer, was missing a parameter for searching all children.

Comment: Not only parameter - now it has wrong return type - `Find(string,bool)` returns array of controls

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn1 = (Button)(Controls.Find("btnName"));
```

This will get the required button and will save the button attributes into a new Button btn1